# Sed and escaping single quote

Tags: shell, sed, ksh

I'm having a problem with sed and single quotes

I have a string like this :

```
-cmd af -i 3 -a
```

I want to change this string to

```
-cmd 'af -i 3 -a'
```

Now I'm using this :

the string is stored in buff variable

```
buff=$(echo $buff | sed -r "s/cmd /CMD '/g")"'"
```

it echoes ok      `-cmd 'af -i 3 -a'`

I then call a function with buff as a parameter and while executing the script with ksh -x I can see the call is NOK

```
+ buff=$'-CMD \'af -i 3 -a \''
+ echo -CMD $'\'af' -i 3 -a $'\''
-CMD 'af -i 3 -a' #this is the echo
+ functionTest -CMD $'\'af' -i 3 -a $'\''
```

As a result it will always  give me

```
-CMD $'\'af' -i 3 -a $'\''
```

So basically it seems my single quotes are interpreted as `$'\''`

I have no idea why, I tried a lot of things such as escaping chars but it gives me the exact same result, even with `\x27`

Comment: If you're trying to store a command with its arguments in a string, you're doing it wrong; you should use an array instead.

Comment: no, just trying to format a string there

Comment: Your command works fine here: `buff="-cmd af -i 3 -a"; buff=$(echo $buff | sed -r "s/cmd /CMD '/g")"'"; echo "$buff"` outputs `-CMD 'af -i 3 -a'`.

Comment: but then I try to call a function with this string as a parameter, and while I ksh -x the call I can see it's formatted the way I put it

-CMD $'\'af' -i 3 -a $'\''

Comment: You should tell us _everything_ in your question. We're not psychics.

Comment: sorry, I edited the main question to add that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you seeing the odd-ball result?

What you've got is OK in the raw (`sed` on Mac OS X does not support `-r`, but the regex used doesn't need the non-standard GNU extension option `-r` anyway):

```
$ buff1="-cmd af -i 3 -a"
$ buff2=$(echo $buff1 | sed -e "s/cmd /CMD '/g")"'"
$ echo $buff2
-CMD 'af -i 3 -a'
$
```

I suspect your problem is not in the transform, but in the way you're viewing the result.

---

#### ksh test

```
Osiris JL: cat so14043243.sh
buff1="-cmd af -i 3 -a"
buff2=$(echo $buff1 | sed -e "s/cmd /CMD '/g")"'"
echo $buff2
echo "$buff2"
Osiris JL: ksh -x so14043243.sh
+ buff1='-cmd af -i 3 -a'
+ sed -e $'s/cmd /CMD \'/g'
+ echo -cmd af -i 3 -a
+ buff2=$'-CMD \'af -i 3 -a\''
+ echo -CMD $'\'af' -i 3 $'-a\''
-CMD 'af -i 3 -a'
+ echo $'-CMD \'af -i 3 -a\''
-CMD 'af -i 3 -a'
Osiris JL:
```

The output is correct; the trace is slightly confusing but the same as what you show.

There is a good reason for the extra effort that the `-x` output goes to; it disambiguates the output so that you can determine exactly what is what, if you can read it well enough.  Also, you could copy'n'paste the line after the `+` and run it and get exactly the same result again.  The old Bourne shell had a `-x` option which did not do character mapping like this, and it could lead to confusion, and you certainly could not reliably copy'n'paste the trace output to execute the command again.

The key point is that the result — what is echoed — is what you want and expect, so you're fretting over nothing (as it happens).  But I agree, it can be confusing at first.

Comment: Okay so it's just a display understanding problem :)
I'll look further in the called function, that's where the problem must be
Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me too. But there's no need for `sed`; bash builtins can do this just fine:

```
$ buff='-cmd af -i 3 -a'
$ buff=${buff/cmd /CMD \'}\'
$ echo $buff
-CMD 'af -i 3 -a'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @gniourf_gniourf's initial comment about storing strings in variables is basically right (even though you're only trying to store command arguments); see [BashFAQ #050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Now, you have two confusions here. The first is that you're misunderstanding what `-x` mode is printing. It doesn't print the arguments to the command you're running, it prints a command *that will pass the same arguments*. In this case, some of the arguments include single-quotes, so it gives a quoted-and-escaped string that, *after quote removal*, will result in the same argument that's actually being passed. For example, one of the arguments is `'af`, so -x mode displays it as `$'\'af'`.

Second, it looks like you're trying to embed single-quotes in the variable, so that you can pass several words to functionTest as a single argument (i.e. you're trying to run the equivalent of `functionTest -CMD 'af -i 3 -a'). If I'm right about what you're trying to do, you're doing it fundamentally wrong. When the shell parses a command line, it interprets quotes and escapes, *then* substitutes variables. It'll go back and split the replaced variables into words, but it will not go back and pay attention to quotes and escapes in the substituted text. So when it replaces`$buff`with`-CMD 'af -i 3 -a'`, it splits that into 5 arguments: "-CMD", "'af", "-i", "3", and "-a'". Note that the single-quotes are treated part of the second and fifth arguments, not as enclosing a single long argument:

```
$ buff="-CMD 'af -i 3 -a'"
$ printargs $buff
Got 5 arguments:
  «-CMD»
  «'af»
  «-i»
  «3»
  «-a'»
```

In order to store multiple arguments without this sort of confusion, you need to use an array (again, see @gniourf_gniourf's comment and [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)):

```
$ buff=(-CMD 'af -i 3 -a')
$ printargs "${buff[@]}"
Got 2 arguments:
  «-CMD»
  «af -i 3 -a»
```

BTW, if you're trying to replicate this, you'll need printargs. It's a really simple shell script I wrote to clarify situations like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Got $# arguments:"
for arg; do
        echo "  «${arg}»"
done
```